# Exclude double quote and single quote from detecting as special character

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Currently im detecting special character using the code below

```
 val specialChars: Pattern = Pattern.compile("[^a-z\\d ]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
            val specialCharMatcher: Matcher = specialChars.matcher(text)
            val hasSpecialChar = specialCharMatcher.find()
```

Is there a way to exclude quote `" "` , single quote `'` , and slash `/` from the detection?

Comment: Your regex already doesn't match those characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude specific characters from the detection by adding them to your regex, like this:

```
"[^a-z\\d '/\"]"
```

Comment: is it possible to add \ backslash in the detection

Comment: Yes you can add it, `"[^a-z\\d '/\"\\\\]"` you need to escape it as it is used as an escape character in regular expressions